# Java database string types and type safety

Tags: java, type-safety

How do you use types which are read from the database and how do you provide type safety in your code?

**Precondition**

Given is a database table with various type columns. Column "A" contains string values "A", "B, "C". Column "B" contains string values "X", "Y", "Z".

**Example Usage**

In order to guarantee type safety I'd rather wrap these values around enums and use the types than to use the values directly as strings.

Something like this:

```
public class TypeSafetyExample {

    /**
     * TypeA: map string type to enum type.
     */
    public enum TypeA {
        A("A"),
        B("B"),
        C("C");

        String id;

        TypeA( String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public static TypeA get( String id) {

            for( TypeA item: EnumSet.allOf(TypeA.class)) {
                if( item.id.equals(id)) {
                    return item;
                }

            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported enum id: " + id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * TypeB: map string type to enum type and give it some other attribute.
     */
    public enum TypeB {
        X("X", true),
        Y("Y", true),
        Z("Z", false);

        String id;
        boolean someAttribute;

        TypeB( String id, boolean someAttribute) {
            this.id = id;
            this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
        }

        public boolean isSomeAttribute() {
            return this.someAttribute;
        }

        public static TypeB get( String id) {

            for( TypeB item: EnumSet.allOf(TypeB.class)) {
                if( item.id.equals(id)) {
                    return item;
                }

            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported enum id: " + id);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Object using enums as types.
     */
    public static class MyObjectTyped {
        TypeA typeA;
        TypeB typeB;

        public String toString() {
            return "Type A: " + typeA + ", Type B: " + typeB;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Object using strings as types.
     */
    public static class MyObjectUntyped {
        String typeA;
        String typeB;

        public String toString() {
            return "Type A: " + typeA + ", Type B: " + typeB;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Example usage.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyObjectTyped objTyped;
        MyObjectUntyped objUntyped;

        // ... here we would read data from the database and create our typed objects ...

        objTyped = new MyObjectTyped();
        objTyped.typeA = TypeA.get( "A");
        objTyped.typeB = TypeB.get( "X");

        System.out.println( objTyped); // Type A: A, Type B: X

        objTyped = new MyObjectTyped();
        objTyped.typeA = TypeA.get( "A");
        objTyped.typeB = TypeB.get( "?"); // Runtime Error during database read: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported enum id: ?

        objUntyped = new MyObjectUntyped();
        objUntyped.typeA = "???"; // no error at all, probably we'll get a runtime error or some inconsistency later, but never during database loading
        objUntyped.typeB = "???"; // no error at all, probably we'll get a runtime error or some inconsistency later, but never during database loading

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Basically for every type an enum is created and the database-string-type is mapped to that enum. In the java code only the enums are used, never the strings.

Advantage of enums:

- consistency check during loading from database

Disadvantage of enums:

- code changes necessary whenever a new type is added

Advantage of strings:

- no code changes necessary when a new type gets added

Disadvantage of strings:

- no type safety. The database can contain anything. Errors during runtime possible.

What do you think of the concepts? Which one do you prefer? Or are there better ways? I rather stick with the type safety because the stability of the code is worth it. On the other hand doing code changes whenever a new type gets added isn't good practice either.

Thank you for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you are using those strings. Does the *logic* of your code depend on the actual value, or is it simply something that you read from the database, perhaps, transform somehow and present to the user or send to some other consumer?

If it is the former, enum may be warranted.

Also note, that you can enforce the constraint at the database level if you want to make sure the strings belong to the known valid set. So, "the database can contain anything" isn't really true.

In general, if you are using the database at all, it should be your "source of truth" for the consistency and validity of data you put there. That's what databases are for, and that's what they are good at. Throwing junk at your data store, and relying on application code to sanitize it on the way out isn't a good idea at all.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the logic depends on the code as well as something is displayed to the user. The mechanism is being used for various types. Unfortunately the database design is out of my hands and several developers from several countries mess with it. So I rather prefer I can prove inconsistencies immediately. I didn't know that you could put constraints on the values of a databse columns. I'll look into it.